# Trying to create a MySQL table with UTC_TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want my create table in MySQL to look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Test_Tbl
(
Create_Date datetime Default UTC_TIMESTAMP()
);
```

However, I continually get an error. I have successfully replaced the UTC_TIMESTAMP() with each of the following and added the table.

```
NOW()
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
LOCALTIME()
LOCALTIMESTAMP()
```

Since I cannot get the UTC functions to work, I am thinking a setting in PHPMyAdmin may need changed? (UTC_DATE and UTC_TIME also fail.)
**
I am working in a XAMP install.
The error states "A comma or closing bracket was expected. (near "(" at position 76)"
Changing the data type to timestamp, makes no difference.
Thanks.

Comment: I am moving on without knowing why I cannot use the UTC functions in my create statement. In my use case, the DATETIME data type allowing dates before 1970 and after 2038 is irrelevant (at least for a couple of years). Therefore, I am changing my data type to TIMESTAMP to get the UTC value saved when the default is Now(). This tutorial helped my learning - http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-timestamp.aspx. The TIMESTAMP data type stores the UTC value but converts it based on the connection's time zone for display purposes.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version is included with your XAMPP install? Version information is available on the main page, in the right hand columns.

Comment: phpMyAdmin version is 4.5.1. (A newer version 4.6.6 is available.)

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21619/33241. This is not the proper place to use `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` and causes errors even at the MySQL command line client.

Comment: @Isaac I agree. Thanks for directing me to that post. Still not sure I understand why UTC functions cannot be used in the creation of the table, but with a data type of 'timestamp' the value will be stored as UTC value. I think my focus on using UTC functions in the Create statement is what caused your suggested post not to show in my searches. Do I flag this as a duplicate or does an administrator? Would you recommend that I edit my question to point to the other post as a precursor to future readers of this question? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't help explain this MySQL behavior other than to say that UTC_TIMESTAMP() is a function meant to be used on retrieved/queried data, and that since timestamps are already stored in UTC format and converted when queried that it wouldn't make much sense to change the behavior. That's my two cents, anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your concern about cleaning up the duplicate link here, but I think there's nothing you can do. Someone with a lot more reputation than me can probably migrate it (since you can't directly mark a duplicate of a question on another Stackoverflow "Network"), but I'd just leave it. Thinking about it, though, the solution should probably be an answer rather than a comment, so I'll post one which you can mark as accepted if you'd like, that way future readers can easily find the answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in far greater detail in the [answers over at dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/20217/33241), this is incorrect syntax here because the function `UTC_TIMESTAMP();` can't be used there. This query fails even at the command line, so upgrading or modifying phpMyAdmin won't help.

The short version of the answer is that since MySQL already stores TIMESTAMP columns as UTC times, this function wouldn't do much in this context. Normally, when you place and retrieve data, MySQL will automatically convert it back to the time zone the client is using. You may also be interested in using some other type such as DATETIME to [avoid this automatic conversion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
create temporary table test(
id int, 
ts timestamp without time zone default (now() at time zone 'utc')
);
```

The following statement will return the current UTC date and time.

```
SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP,UTC_TIMESTAMP();
```

Comment: The Create code you suggested resulted in the following errors: A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "without" at position 58) and Unrecognized statement type. (near "now" at position 86). My apologies if I am being too literal in entering the code as you entered and not knowing something obvious that I should be doing.

Comment: @Amateur fails for me as well with MariaDB 10.3.

Comment: The example is for MySQL. MariaDB currently doesnt support this, see here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/timestamp/